# Codeigniter passing data controller to view

Tags: php, codeigniter

Here is my controller:

```
   class CommonController extends CI_Controller {
      public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
          $this->load->model('common_model'); //load your model my model is "common model"
      }

     public function add_work(){
     $names = $_POST['name'];
     $works = $_POST['work'];

     $allValues = array(); // array to contains inserted rows 
     foreach($names as $key => $name){
             $name= "your specified name";
             $insertdata = array();
             $insertdata['work'] = $works[$key];
             $insertdata['name'] = $name;
             $this->common_model->insert($insertdata);

             array_push($allValues,$insertdata);
        //$insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO work(name,work) values ( '$name','$work')");
            }
  foreach($allValues as $insertRow){
     echo $insertRow['work'];
     echo $insertRow['name'];//this shows data well. but how to pass data in view.php
  }
  //view code will add here to show data in browser
}
```

Basically I want to pass all data to view.php for printing or exporting purpose. How can I do so.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/zmrnKMUZ

shows  `Message: Undefined variable: stockdata`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To load a view you should do like this.

```
$this->load->view("filename");
```

If you want to pass data to view, you should do like this.

```
$this->load->view("filename",$data);
```

`$data` should have all parameters which you want to print in view.

The syntax goes like this.

```
$this->load->view("filename","data to view","Returning views as data(true / false");
```

If third parameter is true, view will come as data. It will not go to browser as output.

**Edit:**

Change

```
$this->load->view('print_view',$insertdata);
```

to

```
$data['insertdata'] = $insertdata; 
$this->load->view('print_view',$data);
```

For more info, check [this link](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html)

Comment: `Message: Undefined variable: stockdata`

Here is pastebin:  http://pastebin.com/zmrnKMUZ

Comment: in this file, that variable is used by that name `stockdata`.

Comment: Changed but shows `Message: Undefined variable: insertdata `

Comment: @russell You cannot use data like that. Change this 
`$data['insertdata']` = $insertdata;
`$this->load->view('print_view',$data);`

Comment: Please check my updated answer. Check only edited part.

Comment: Check my values are in foreach loop. how to get them

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92597/discussion-between-niranjan-n-raju-and-russell).

Comment: @russell pplease check chat.

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju Both document version now found here http://www.codeigniter.com/docs

Answer (score 4):

**How CI Classes Pass Information and Control to Each Other**

**Calling Views**
We will see.how the controller calls a view and passes data to it:
First it creates an array of data ($data) to pass to the view; then it loads and calls the view in the same expression:

```
$this->load->view('testview', $data);
```

You can call libraries, models, plug-ins, or helpers from within any controller, and models and libraries can also call each other as well as plug-ins and helpers.
However, you can't call one controller from another, or call a controller from a
model or library. There are only two ways that a model or a library can refer back to a controller:
Firstly, it can return data. If the controller assigns a value like this:

```
$foo = $this->mymodel->myfunction();
```

and the function is set to return a value, then that value will be passed to the variable $foo inside the controller.

//sample

```
 public function display()
     {
     $data['text_to_display'] = $this->text_to_display;
     $data['text_color'] = $this->text_color;
     $this->load->view('display_view',$data);
     }
```

**Adding Dynamic Data to the View**

Data is passed from the controller to the view by way of an array or an object in the second parameter of the view
loading method. Here is an example using an array:

```
$data = array(
’title’ => ’some’,
’heading’ => ’another some’,
’message’ => ’and another some’
);
$this->load->view(’view’, $data);
```

And here’s an example using an object:

```
$data = new Someclass();
$this->load->view(’view’, $data);
```

**Sending Multiple Dimensional array**

if we pull data from your database it will typically be
in the form of a multi-dimensional array.

```
<?php
class foo extends CI_Controller {
public function index()
{
$data[’Books’] = array(’POEAA’, ’TDD’, ’Clean C’);
$data[’title’] = "Title";
$data[’heading’] = "Heading";
$this->load->view(’view’, $data);
}
}
```

in view

```
<html>
<head>
<title><?php echo $title;?></title>
</head>
<body>
<h1><?php echo $heading;?></h1>
<h3>My Books List</h3>
<ul>
<?php foreach ($Books as $item):?>
<li><?php echo $item;?></li>
<?php endforeach;?>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

[More Learning](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/views.html)

**NOTE:**

There is a third optional parameter lets you change the behavior of the method so that it returns data as a string rather
than sending it to your browser.The default behavior is false, which sends it to your browser. Remember to
assign it to a variable if you want the data returned:

```
$string = $this->load->view(’view’, ’’, TRUE);
```

Above will not solve your problem directly but definetly help in understanding concepts.

Comment: i have read the article about how to pass data From Controller To View In CodeIgniter 
https://www.cloudways.com/blog/how-to-pass-data-in-codeigniter/

Comment: @OwasisAlam so what do you want from me?